# the category city made as a subdomain

Tags: categories, subdomains

i'm looking for a solution wherein the category city will be made as a subdomain. For example, when a user search for a certain thing in the main domain and under a certain city, the user will be directed to the subdomain "city.domain.com". same to a user who uploaded a product, for example, under a city - the product will be automatically be under the city category, which could then be viewed in the subdomain. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try a [Multi-Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) install? Or this may be outdated but you could try the [wordpress-subdomains plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/)